Replicateing an integral from a paper
Let $R(\phi_n) := |\phi_n|^2 (\phi_{n+1} + \phi_{n-1} - 2\phi_n)$ where $\phi_n := \frac{\sinh \mu}{\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}e^{ik(n-x_0)+i\alpha}$.
Consider the ODE
\begin{equation}\dot{k} = -\epsilon \sinh \mu\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\mu(n-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}{\cosh\mu(n+1-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-1-x_0)}Re\{R(\phi_n)e^{-ik(n-x_0)-i\alpha}\}\end{equation}
According to the below except from  https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.53.1172, equation $(35)$ is obtained from applying $(A5)$ to $(A4)$. However, in my attempt, I have a factor of $cos(k)$ which does not go away.  


Attempt:
Equation $(A5)$ is obtained by taking the Fourier transform of $(A4)$ and applying a change of variable $x = \mu n - \mu x_0$ and also taking only the first harmonic of the Dirichlet kernel $s=1$. This yields
\begin{equation}
\int_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\frac{dx}{\mu}\phi(x)(1 + 2\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{\mu})),
\end{equation}
where $\phi(x):= \frac{\tanh x \cosh x}{(\cosh x \cosh \mu + \sinh x \sinh \mu)(\cosh x \cosh \mu - \sinh x \sinh \mu)}\frac{1}{\cosh^{2}x}\left ( \frac{\cos k}{\cosh x \cosh \mu + \sinh x \sinh \mu}  + \frac{\cos k}{\cosh x \cosh \mu - \sinh x \sinh \mu} - 2\frac{1}{\cosh x}\right )$
Rewriting the function in terms of exponentials $e^{x}$ and $e^{\mu}$ and a change of variables $y:=e^{x}$, $c := e^{\mu}$, the integrand becomes a rational function of polynomials which can theoretically be handled via partial fraction decomposition. However, note that there are still the $\cos k$ factors. Even if I perform PFD, they do not go away I think. And yet, equation $(35)$ has no $k$ dependence. Am I on the wrong track?
